# How to permanently disable mediaserver service?

Tags: battery-life, command-line, services, media-scanner, disable-app

I am trying to permanently disable the  notorious power hogging `mediascanserver` or `mediaserver` (whatever it's better known) service on a rooted Jiayu S3.

Here are my ADB commands:

```
su
pm disable com.android.providers.media/com.android.providers.media.MediaScannerReceiver
top > /mnt/sdcard2/toplist.txt  #Polling the output of top
```

Now getting the file here on my PC:

```
adb pull /mnt/sdcard2/toplist.txt c:\adbf\toplist.txt
```

MediaServer process on line 242 in below o/p. So, my questions are:

1. Why `pm disable` did not work for Mediaserver?
2. Is there any other Android service in the below o/p which is running
   as a hack or resource hog and deserves to be disabled?
3. For a specific process I see below, how do I go about finding out the **corresponding service** name, so that the same can be disabled.

   E.g. the line `# 241 drmserver`. What is that process? How do you get the service name for it?

---

```
User 2%, System 1%, IOW 47%, IRQ 0%
User 13 + Nice 0 + Sys 11 + Idle 304 + IOW 299 + IRQ 0 + SIRQ 0 = 627

  PID PR CPU% S  #THR     VSS     RSS PCY UID      Name
 9627  1   2% S    13 1031512K  49716K  bg u0_a8    com.google.android.gms:snet
 9751  1   1% R     1   1492K    488K     root     top
 9578  1   0% S    87 1287976K  88152K  fg u0_a8    com.google.android.gms
  971  0   0% S    39 1065904K 207896K  fg u0_a12   com.android.systemui
  796  0   0% D     1      0K      0K     root     jbd2/mmcblk1p2-
  129  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     mmcqd/1
  177  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/1:1H
   10  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     rcu_sched
   11  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     migration/1
   12  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ksoftirqd/1
   14  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/1:0H
   15  2   0% R     1      0K      0K     root     migration/2
   16  2   0% R     1      0K      0K     root     ksoftirqd/2
   18  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/2:0H
   19  3   0% R     1      0K      0K     root     migration/3
   20  3   0% R     1      0K      0K     root     ksoftirqd/3
   22  3   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/3:0H
   23  4   0% R     1      0K      0K     root     migration/4
   24  4   0% R     1      0K      0K     root     ksoftirqd/4
   26  4   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/4:0H
   27  5   0% R     1      0K      0K     root     migration/5
   28  5   0% R     1      0K      0K     root     ksoftirqd/5
   30  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/5:0H
   31  6   0% R     1      0K      0K     root     migration/6
   32  6   0% R     1      0K      0K     root     ksoftirqd/6
   33  6   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/6:0
   34  6   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/6:0H
   35  7   0% R     1      0K      0K     root     migration/7
   36  7   0% R     1      0K      0K     root     ksoftirqd/7
   37  7   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/7:0
   38  7   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/7:0H
   39  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     khelper
   40  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     fs_sync
   41  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     suspend
   42  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     writeback
   43  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     bioset
   44  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     crypto
   45  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kblockd
   46  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     khubd
   48  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     pool_reload_wor
   49  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     cmdq_auto_relea
   50  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     cmdq_task
   51  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/5:1
   52  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     cfg80211
   53  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     cfinteractive
   54  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     pmic_6325_threa
   55  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     bat_percent_not
   56  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     emi_mpu
   57  1   0% D     1      0K      0K     root     hps_main
   58  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     mt_gpufreq_inpu
   59  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kswapd0
   60  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     fsnotify_mark
   79  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     uether
   80  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ion_mm_heap
   81  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     binder
   90  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     MD32_CUST_PIN_W
   91  0   0% D     1      0K      0K     root     hang_detect
   92  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     btif_rxd
   93  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     sensor_polling
   94  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     conn-md-thread
   95  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_cldma_worke
   96  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_tx0_worker
   97  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_tx1_worker
   98  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_tx2_worker
   99  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_tx3_worker
  100  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_tx4_worker
  101  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_tx5_worker
  102  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_tx6_worker
  103  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_tx7_worker
  104  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_rx0_worker
  105  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_rx1_worker
  106  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_rx2_worker
  107  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_rx3_worker
  108  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_rx4_worker
  109  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_rx5_worker
  110  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_rx6_worker
  111  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     md1_rx7_worker
  112  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ccci_ctrl
  113  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ccci_sys
  114  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ccci_poll
  115  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ccci_rpc
  116  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ccci_ipc_3
  117  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ccci_ipc_4
  118  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     accdet
  119  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     keyEvent_send
  120  6   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     accdet_disable
  121  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     accdet_eint
  122  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     mtk_vibrator
  123  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     hall_eint
  124  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     MD32_REBOOT_WQ
  125  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     mmcqd/0
  126  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     mmcqd/0boot0
  127  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     mmcqd/0boot1
  128  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     mmcqd/0rpmb
  130  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     pmic_6311_threa
  131  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ddp_irq_log_kth
  132  5   0% D     1      0K      0K     root     display_esd_che
  133  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     display_check_a
  134  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     fence_worker
    1  0   0% S     1    940K    796K     root     /init
  136  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     frame_update_wo
  137  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     disp_switch_mod
  138  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kthermp
  140  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     PTP_CTRL_MCUSYS
  141  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     PTP_CTRL_GPUSYS
  142  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     PTP_CTRL_SOC
  143  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     deferwq
  144  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     f_mtp
  145  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     file-storage
  146  0   0% D     1      0K      0K     root     wdtk-0
  147  1   0% D     1      0K      0K     root     wdtk-1
  148  1   0% D     1      0K      0K     root     wdtk-2
  149  0   0% D     1      0K      0K     root     wdtk-3
  150  1   0% D     1      0K      0K     root     wdtk-4
  151  0   0% D     1      0K      0K     root     wdtk-5
  152  0   0% D     1      0K      0K     root     wdtk-6
  153  0   0% D     1      0K      0K     root     wdtk-7
  154  0   0% D     1      0K      0K     root     bat_thread_kthr
  155  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     mtk charger_hv_
  158  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/6:1
  159  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     synaptics-tpd
  160  7   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     dsx_exp_workque
  162  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/7:1
  163  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/2:1
  164  7   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/7:1H
  165  6   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/6:1H
  166  5   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/5:1H
  167  4   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/4:1
  168  3   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/3:1
  169  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     fwu_workqueue
  170  0   0% S     1    748K    456K     root     /sbin/ueventd
  172  4   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/4:1H
  173  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/0:1H
  174  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     jbd2/mmcblk0p16
  175  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ext4-dio-unwrit
  181  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     jbd2/mmcblk0p18
  182  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ext4-dio-unwrit
  186  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     jbd2/mmcblk0p17
  187  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ext4-dio-unwrit
  193  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     jbd2/mmcblk0p3-
  194  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ext4-dio-unwrit
  200  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     jbd2/mmcblk0p4-
  201  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ext4-dio-unwrit
  221  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     loop0
  225  1   0% S     1   2480K    164K  fg root     /sbin/healthd
  226  0   0% S     1   1208K    424K     system   /system/bin/servicemanager
  227  0   0% S     3   5088K   1160K     root     /system/bin/vold
  229  4   0% S     1   1084K    424K     system   /system/bin/logwrapper
  230  0   0% S     2   3852K   2036K     system   /system/bin/autokd
  231  0   0% S     1   1564K    716K     ccci     /system/bin/ccci_fsd
  233  1   0% S     1   1592K    640K     system   /system/bin/ccci_mdinit
  236  1   0% S     8  10700K   1904K     root     /system/bin/netd
  238  1   0% S    28 180600K  11524K     system   /system/bin/surfaceflinger
  239  0   0% S     1   1096K    476K     system   /system/bin/6620_launcher
  240  1   0% S     4 972332K  36120K     root     zygote
  241  0   0% S     3  17368K   3060K  fg drm      /system/bin/drmserver
  242  1   0% S    20 104900K  21488K  fg media    /system/bin/mediaserver
  243  1   0% S     1   1204K    572K     install  /system/bin/installd
  244  4   0% S     2   4816K    664K  fg system   /system/bin/nvram_backup_binder
  245  0   0% S     1   4700K   1252K  fg keystore /system/bin/keystore
  248  1   0% S     2   2456K    668K     shell    /system/bin/mobile_log_d
  249  3   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/3:1H
  250  2   0% S     1   1408K    288K     system   /system/bin/drvbd
  251  1   0% S     2   3176K    636K     shell    /system/bin/netdiag
  254  0   0% S     2   5132K   1012K  fg system   /system/bin/dm_agent_binder
  255  0   0% S     2   4828K    800K  fg system   /system/bin/ppl_agent
  257  0   0% S     2   4600K    712K  fg radio    /system/bin/vtservice
  260  2   0% S    34  38864K   1324K     gps      /system/bin/mtk_agpsd
  261  0   0% S     1   1092K    448K     wifi     /system/bin/wifi2agps
  262  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/2:1H
  266  1   0% S     1   3256K    552K     gps      /system/xbin/mnld
  268  1   0% S     4   6836K    768K  fg system   /system/bin/nvram_agent_binder
  270  0   0% S     3   3172K    480K     system   /system/bin/thermal
  271  0   0% S     1   1072K    392K     system   /system/bin/thermald
  274  0   0% S     1   1076K    408K     shell    /system/bin/batterywarning
  275  2   0% S     2   4904K    660K  fg media    /system/bin/MtkCodecService
  276  1   0% S     4  18472K   4664K  fg system   /system/bin/guiext-server
  285  0   0% S     5  20092K   5368K     bluetoot /system/bin/mtkbt
  286  2   0% S     3   4012K   1180K     media_rw /system/bin/sdcard
  287  2   0% S     1   1268K    556K     root     /system/bin/sh
  288  1   0% S     2  29888K   5024K     nvram    /system/bin/em_svr
  289  0   0% S     1    688K     88K     root     /system/xbin/su
  290  0   0% S     5   4720K    336K     shell    /sbin/adbd
  413  2   0% S     1   1520K    376K     system   /system/bin/qmc6983d
  565  3   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kbase_event
  695  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     mtk_stp_psm
  696  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     mtk_stp_btm
  698  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     mtk_wmtd
  699  4   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     fm_timer_wq
  700  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     fm_eint_wq
  762  2   0% S     2   2768K    736K     shell    /system/bin/emdlogger1
  763  0   0% S    15  15484K    608K     radio    /system/bin/gsm0710muxd
  769  0   0% S    87 1110380K 109204K  fg system   system_server
  797  3   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ext4-dio-unwrit
  842  1   0% S    27  30892K    884K     radio    /system/bin/rild
  914  0   0% S    29 1037980K  93056K  fg u0_a12   com.android.keyguard
  946  0   0% S    12 987640K  37592K  fg system   com.mediatek.security
 1010  0   0% S     1   3924K   1760K     wifi     /system/bin/wpa_supplicant
 1047  1   0% S    60 1055124K  54124K  fg radio    com.android.phone
 1076  6   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kbase_event
 1163  0   0% S    16 1074896K  75084K  fg u0_a76   com.mediatek.voicecommand
 1176  0   0% S    12 988264K  31588K  fg bluetoot com.mediatek.bluetooth
 1191  0   0% S    10 994012K  27928K  fg system   com.mediatek.voiceextension
 1204  0   0% S    28 1010356K  39268K  fg nfc      com.android.nfc
 1226  3   0% S     2   2112K    448K     system   /system/bin/fotabinder
 1250  0   0% S    15 994204K  42948K  fg u0_a82   ace.jun.simplecontrol:remote
 1304  1   0% S    12  12980K    744K  fg nfc      nfcstackp
 1430  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kbase_event
 1480  0   0% S    14 990396K  40752K  fg u0_a8    com.google.process.location
 1845  3   0% S     3   4132K   1264K     media_rw /system/bin/sdcard
 2083  1   0% S    30 1012772K  43020K  fg bluetoot com.android.bluetooth
 2599  1   0% S    12 987356K  33744K  fg u0_a71   org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service:remote
 2678  1   0% S    14 997032K  46344K  fg u0_a51   com.android.inputmethod.latin
 2914  0   0% S    48 1075680K  59368K  bg u0_a8    com.google.android.gms.persistent
 3168  0   0% S     1   1808K    688K     root     /system/bin/debuggerd.bin
 4761  1   0% S     2   2124K    400K  bg u0_a79   /data/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/files/libestool2.so
 5721  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/2:2
 5948  0   0% S    20 1004756K  41372K  bg u0_a3    android.process.acore
 6038  0   0% S    55 1060916K  76220K  fg u0_a124  com.google.android.inputmethod.latin
 6061  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kbase_event
 6140  1   0% S    49 1057276K 157788K  bg u0_a167  com.gau.go.launcherex
 6212  1   0% S    12 993280K  28296K  bg u0_a167  com.gau.go.launcherex:remote
 6232  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kbase_event
 6453  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/0:2
 6564  0   0% S    21 1005012K  38684K  bg u0_a167  com.gau.go.launcherex:com.jiubang.commerce.service.IntelligentP
 6998  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/u17:2
 7777  1   0% S    10 986336K  27864K  bg u0_a33   com.android.deskclock
 8016  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/3:2
 8028  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/0:0
 8381  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/4:2
 8510  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/u17:0
 8676  0   0% S    10 984768K  28552K  bg system   com.adups.fota.sysoper
 8811  0   0% S    23 1006572K  34660K  bg u0_a134  com.stackexchange.marvin
 8889  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/u16:2
 9047  1   0% S    66 1087948K  58556K  bg u0_a120  com.google.android.youtube
 9130  0   0% S    15 996944K  45700K  bg u0_a163  com.fsck.k9
 9154  0   0% S    51 1053048K  54072K  bg u0_a117  com.whatsapp
 9197  0   0% S    35 1028400K  49308K  bg u0_a16   com.android.vending
 9284  2   0% S    23 1078192K 104912K     system   com.android.settings
 9305  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kbase_event
 9329  0   0% S    40 1041464K  50512K  bg u0_a169  com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping
 9401  1   0% S    12 987404K  29980K  bg u0_a96   com.opera.mini.android
 9416  1   0% S    11 993256K  30976K  bg u0_a108  com.chrome.beta
 9431  0   0% S    12 995316K  39588K  bg u0_a79   com.estrongs.android.pop
 9478  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/5:2
 9485  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/u16:4
 9533  1   0% S    10 989156K  37696K  bg u0_a126  com.quoord.tapatalkxda.activity
 9644  2   0% S    11 1027560K  34304K  bg u0_a8    com.google.android.gms.wearable
 9668  0   0% S    24 1042860K  52900K  bg u0_a8    com.google.android.gms.unstable
 9699  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kbase_event
 9715  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/0:1
 9718  1   0% S     1   1268K    580K     shell    /system/bin/sh
 9723  0   0% S     1    688K      4K     shell    su
 9724  1   0% S     3   2748K     36K     shell    su
 9727  1   0% S     1    692K     40K     root     /system/xbin/su
 9729  1   0% S     1    692K     48K     root     /system/xbin/su
 9730  1   0% S     1   1052K    508K     root     sh
10812  0   0% S    30 1020908K  56760K  bg u0_a158  com.truecaller
13675  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kbase_event
15254  1   0% S    11 993728K  28416K  bg u0_a129  com.android.gallery3d
15424  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/u17:3
15624  1   0% S    36 1075904K  67664K  bg u0_a149  com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
18905  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/1:2
19367  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/u16:3
26457  1   0% S    14 988616K  28116K  bg u0_a17   com.svox.pico
28050  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ksdioirqd/mmc2
28051  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     stp_sdio_tx_rx
28061  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/1:3
28075  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     tx_thread
28076  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     hif_thread
28077  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     rx_thread
28502  0   0% S    35 1068580K  58328K  fg u0_a8    com.google.process.gapps
29545  1   0% S    11 986236K  35432K  bg system   com.android.fallen
30218  0   0% S    13 1002492K  43340K  bg u0_a139  com.google.android.apps.photos
31306  0   0% S    14 992248K  39544K  bg u0_a6    android.process.media
32104  0   0% S     1   1088K    436K     dhcp     /system/bin/logwrapper
32105  1   0% S     1   1204K    644K     dhcp     /system/bin/dhcpcd
32567  3   0% S     1    688K      4K     u0_a79   su
32569  1   0% S     1    692K     32K     u0_a79   su
32571  3   0% S     1    692K     36K     root     /system/xbin/su
32572  3   0% S     1    692K     44K     root     /system/xbin/su
32573  3   0% S     1   1040K    324K     root     sh
32609  3   0% S     1   1020K    272K     root     /data/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/files/libestool2.so
  135  0   0% D     1      0K      0K     root     present_fence_w
    2  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kthreadd
    3  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ksoftirqd/0
    5  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/0:0H
    7  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     migration/0
    8  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     rcu_preempt
    9  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     rcu_bh
```

Comment: Could you post the `AndroidManifest.xml` of your `com.android.process.media`'s apk? I don't see such component in my device. // Also, there is a file  `/system/bin/mediaserver`. Have you considered it yet?

Comment: yes I see that as well and I guess that is the question I asked, part of it . If I see a process running how do I get the corresponding service name so I can use p m disable on that process. Regards the XML file could you please tell me how to go about getting that .I searched using a rooted file explorer for this file or close match but nothing turned up

Comment: You'll have to extract the XML file from that `com.android.process.media` (common name could be different like Mediaserver.apk) apk; ES file Explorer could do it. And by considering `/system/bin/mediaserver` I meant to revoke its executable permissions, reboot and see if the notorious service is gone.

Comment: I could try that. Ok once I identify the apk file could you please tell me how to get the xml file is there a specific tool that will break open an apk and get the xml out of it

Comment: Any file Archiver tool could open an APK file (it's an archive too). That AndroidManifest.xml file is at the first level of extracted content, you would see it when you would open the extracted folder. You might not be able to open it, so either use [Axel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.xgouchet.xmleditor) to open it, or host the file online and I would see what component you used in your command.

Comment: . It did not work Mediaserver still runs on my Android 4.4 Jiayu S3 phone as /system/bin/mediaserver and I found another just as pricky process called /system/bin/drmserverwhich shows up on adb # top . So I mounted the /system in RW mode and removed -x from them both. After that I killed the existing processes for these binaries. The phone just froze . After a force restart it will NOT BOOT until I restored the -x bit again ( restored execute ) . What do these do . How do I ensure they don't run if they are not needed.

Comment: I will get the xml and post it shortly thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

I am not a programmer by any means, but Adups might be the issue. They were in the news today for installing software on phones that dumps data from your phone regularly into a Chinese server.  Heres the link to the story.

http://mobile.nytimes.com/2016/11/16/us/politics/china-phones-software-security.html?referer=https://www.google.com/

This is the only mention of adups in your output:

system   com.adups.fota.sysoper
 8811  0   0% S    23 1006572K  34660K  b

This could be something completely different and harmless, but it's worth looking into. Good luck.